# Web API & Azure Mobile App, should I keep them separated?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

I'm planning a project in which I have a windows service installed in on premise machines (about one hundred of them) which should keep in sync an online azure SQL db with the on premise ones (MS access, third party). That sync happens by calling a Web API.

I then have to build a mobile app which will be used by ~3k users that will access the synced data with Azure mobile app backend.

As for now I've started building a single mobile app backend project which serves both mobile app requests, and webapi2 requests used to sync data. 
Furthermore I'll need to add queue/topic section to send realtime notifications from the app to on premise services.

My concern is if is it good practice to keep both "mobile app" and webapi2 in the same project, or should I separate them.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should, separate them. Based on your description, you should use the microservices architecture, you can read more about it in the links below.

Azure specific:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/microservices
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/

In general:

https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about microservices, but given the relatively small application size and the fact that I'm the only developer, aren't the overhead of interservice communication, and the sync of multiple databases just overhang the microservices benefits?

Comment: It is small now, but I'm almost sure that in a few month from now it will be bigger. Inter service communication is necessary, but sync data is not an issue, because there should be no duplication. One service is responsible for its own data, you should not sync it, if you need it, you just call the service to get it. But, you're right, if it is small, and you know it will stay this way, you should not over complicate it as the KISS principle recommends :)

Comment: In general you're right, but in my particular case using microservices still feels somehow wrong to me. The data here are exactly the same. Furthermore under the hood both actors will use webapi2 technology . As the data is the same, wouldn't that mean that this should be responsability of a single service operating over them?

Comment: The architecture is not bound to the technology, so I think it does not matter that both actors will use webapi2 technology. But, the data does, if you can't split that up, then yes, that means that you should have one service.